# Farewell Emrakul, here's a truly puzzling goodbye

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, steganography

Sadly, our moderator [Emrakul](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20/emrakul) is [stepping down](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/so-long-and-thanks-for-all-the-fish). They've done a fantastic job, so if they have to leave, let's see them off in true puzzling fashion!

There is a message for them hidden here, can you find it?

> Allocate (6)
>   Possessed (3) Oak fruit (5)
>   Behind (3) Charged Particle (3)
>   Arm End (4) Thick paper (4)
>   Washing bowls (6)
>   Jewish skull cap (8)
>   Create (4) Draw parallel lines (4)
>   Help (3) is departed (4)
>   Japanese car company (6)
>   Child’s object (3) female domestic servant (4)
>   Makes a difficult to remove mark (6)
>   Curved structure (4) Arm’s end (4)
>   Very old (4) charged particle (3)
>   Canine (3) IX (4)
>   Infant (3) is departed (4)
>   Firm (4) cylindrical containers (4)

**What is the message?**

Hint:

> The promised end

Second hint:

> Character names are the key to a story

Comment: This is relevant to Emrak's name. The first step can be done, the second requires some extra knowledge

Comment: … first requires knowledge or that is already Steganography?

Comment: @JanIvan No, the first step isn't really anything, the second step requires knowledge to do steganography

Comment: I mean: Oak fruit (5) => Acorn, or Jewish skull cap (8) => yarmulke, that is knowledge imo. But if I'm going wrong way..... because Arm’s end (4) or Arm end (4) I have no idea, so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @JanIvan that's correct, and that's not the knowledge

Comment: This is clever. I like this. Thanks, @BeastlyGerbil :]

Comment: @Emrakul you're welcome! Someone had to do something related to your name! :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The message is

> GOODBYE AND THANKS.

Here are the solutions to the clues:

> `G ASSIGN    Allocate (6)
>    O  HAD ACORN Possessed (3) Oak fruit (5)
>     O ASS ION   Behind (3) Charged Particle (3)
>    D  HAND CARD Arm End (4) Thick paper (4)
>     B BASINS    Washing bowls (6)
>   Y   YARMULKE  Jewish skull cap (8)
>    E  MAKE RULE Create (4) Draw parallel lines (4)
>  A    AID GONE  Help (3) is departed (4)
>     N NISSAN    Japanese car company (6)
>    (D)TOY MAID  Child’s object (3) female domestic servant (4)
>     T STAINS    Makes a difficult to remove mark (6)
>    H  ARCH HAND Curved structure (4) Arm’s end (4)
>  A    AGED ION  Very old (4) charged particle (3)
>  N    DOG NINE  Canine (3) IX (4)
>  K    KID GONE  Infant (3) is departed (4)
>    S  HARD CANS Firm (4) cylindrical containers (4)`

Observe that

> solutions fall into groups that are near-anagrams. The columns at the left hold the discrepant letters. They spell out GOODBYE AND THANKS. I will explain the wrong-looking TOY MAID line below.

Now, the

> "non-discrepant" letters in each set are: ASSIN, HADACRN, ARMULKE, IDGONE. These are anagrams of NISSA, CHANDRA, EMRAKUL (of *course*!) and GIDEON. The only one of these I found was EMRAKUL; elias, in comments, found the others and remarks that they are important characters associated with Emrakul in *Magic: the Gathering* as described e.g. [here](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Emrakul). And now (again, this is elias's find) we can explain TOY MAID too: it's D plus TAMIYO, another such character.

So in fact

> I think my formulation above in terms of near-anagrams is misleading; the actual rule is that each row yields an anagram of an MtG character associated with Emrakul, plus one other letter.

Comment: Oh very nice find - I think this is most if not all of it

Comment: There are two 8-letter sets, no? EMRAKUL and HANDCAR. Not that I have found a better anagram by adding it.

Comment: Looks like these are anagrams of Gideon, Nissa and Chandra, who are all important characters in [this story](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Emrakul) - also Tamiyo appears, which explains 'TOY MAID'

Comment: @elias: Aha, hence the knowledge tag.

Comment: Aha! That would be knowledge I completely 100% didn't have. Thanks, @elias! Will update answer accordingly.

Comment: and yes, @MOehm, indeed there are two 8-letter sets; my apologies for the brain failure.

Comment: Well, your brain had it right when identifying the extra letters, you just missed it in the last part.

Comment: Your last paragraph is correct. I will check the error in a sec

Comment: Updated MARK RULE to MAKE RULE. Thanks for pointing that out, I even  had 'make rule' written, down just misread it as 'mark rule' somehow.

Comment: Ah, this is why you got that shiny new diamond.  For guessing this message correctly.  ;)